# JSF invalid path for ui:include with parameter

Tags: java, jsf, uiinclude

I've faced a strange problem recently with JSF 2.3 using Primefaces 6.2.

I use an ui:include with GET parameter directly in src like so:

```
<ui:include src="../page1.xhtml?id=2">
```

When I run code in netbeans (tomcat 9.0) on Linux everything work great: relative path is working, parameter is available at facescontext....getRequestParameterMap() and so on, but when I run the same project on Windows, JSF tells me that this is an invalid path, and just before this tells something about mime type problem (JSF1091) suggesting to insert a mime type mapping in web.xml

Url comes from db so I would like to figure out a way to do this without using ui:param, mostly because on linux it works already great (exception made in case I have to work with ui:param for some reason).

Is this something releated to OS? Why on Windows (same settings of Linux) it doesn't work?
I try to remove the "?id=2" part from url and the invalid path error went away, so I think the question mark in some way makes troubles.